# Countif with Day before condition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a code to count every route from bus by departure date, but i need to count the day before of the departure on weekdays: Wednesday, Friday and Sunday.

For example if there is 1 bus on the route 148 and date: "Tuesday, 2019-02-05" , i expecting this number count in "Wednesday, 2019-02-06" with the count of this day.

This is the normal input to count by date:

```
   Select departureDate, countif(Route) 
   from table 
   group by departureDate
```

this query gives me the actual Results:

```
  departureDate countif(Route)
  Mon 04-feb-19     1
  Tue 05-feb-19     1
  Wed 06-feb-19     2
  Thu 07-feb-19     1
  Fri 08-feb-19     1
  Sat 09-feb-19     2
  Sun 10-feb-19     2
```

But i am expecting these results:

```
  departureDate countif(Route)      explanation
  Mon 04-feb-19     0                 No count
  Tue 05-feb-19     0                 No count
  Wed 06-feb-19     3                 1 + 1 + 2
  Thu 07-feb-19     0                 No count
  Fri 08-feb-19     2                   1 + 1
  Sat 09-feb-19     0                 No count
  Sun 10-feb-19     4                   2 + 2
```

Comment: can you please clarify why counts are 0(zeroes) for 05-feb-19, 07-feb-19 and 09-feb-19 in example of your expected output. also - you should provide example of input data for which you shown expected output

Comment: yes there are 0, i don't why is showing like this.......i putted in columns

Comment: my question is  - can you explain the logic of why you expect to see zeroes in those dates?! and provide example of input data that will give that output - so we can actually help you w/o wasting our time for reverse engineering your use-case - please do! ;o)

Comment: i already change it, can you undersatnding better now??, i want a sum with date before

Comment: please read my comments again! none is addressed!

Comment: sorry for insisting  - but my question is  - explain why there is "No count" for 05-feb-19, 07-feb-19 and 09-feb-19 - it might be obvious for you - but believe me  - for us who do not know your use case  - it make very low sense if at all - so without having logic for thos"No count" we will not be able to help

Comment: Is simple, all the counts the day before, it should be count in the next day, i don't why is hard to undestand it

Comment: in this case  - why you don't expect count=3 on 07-feb-19  (1 for 07-feb-19 + 2 for 06-feb-19 ) ??? that simple :o) definitelly something else in your mind that you think is obvious - but it is not  - so you need to reveal it ;o)

Comment: Ok, i got it, the reason is because those week days are Wensday, Friday, and Sunday, i need those days with count, i express myself better??

Comment: LOL - finally!!!  so check my understanding - you only want counting for Wed, Friday and Sunday? So that Mon and Tue added to Wed, Thu is added to Fri and Sat added to Sun - is this your logic?

Comment: yes, it is, sorry for the miss understanding

Comment: no problem, we are here to help you even with formulating your problem / case. so I think now it is clear and I would suggest you to update your question with all this important details! hope next time in your next questions you will be more specific - good luck :o)

Comment: done, if you recomend me more details, please let me know

Comment: Perfect, as soon as I can, I will test it, thanks

Comment: any luck? did you have chance to try?

Comment: Not yet, please let me 13 hours to check this

Comment: sure. no rush at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  departureDate, 
  IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM departureDate) IN (1, 4, 6), ANY_VALUE(cnt), 0) cnt 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    departureDate, 
    COUNT(1) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(departureDate) RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE Route = 148
)
GROUP BY departureDate
```

Should be good start for you

You can test, play with above using sample data as in below dummy example that attempts to resemble your example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-04' departureDate, 148 route UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-05', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-06', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-06', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-07', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-08', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-09', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-09', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-10', 148 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-10', 148 
)
SELECT 
  departureDate, 
  IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM departureDate) IN (1, 4, 6), ANY_VALUE(cnt), 0) cnt 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    departureDate, 
    COUNT(1) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(departureDate) RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE Route = 148
)
GROUP BY departureDate
-- ORDER BY departureDate
```

with result

```
Row departureDate   cnt  
1   2019-02-04      0    
2   2019-02-05      0    
3   2019-02-06      3    
4   2019-02-07      0    
5   2019-02-08      2    
6   2019-02-09      0     
7   2019-02-10      4
```

Comment: i have problems for the UNIX_DATE(departureDate) because is a DATETIME, and the function only supports DATE

Comment: anyway - to translate `DATETIME` to `DATE` you can use `DATE(TIMESTAMP(departureDate))`

Comment: i have two more columns base on countif, like this : COUNTIF( RouteId = 134 ) + COUNTIF( RouteId = 60 ) AS Bus_3,
  COUNTIF( RouteId = 134 AND EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM  DepartureDate) = 6) + COUNTIF( RouteId = 60 AND EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM  DepartureDate) = 6)  AS BUS_4, and now i have problems with the sign "+"

Comment: I have answered your original question - please accept it and post your next question(s) and I (or someone else here on SO) will be happy to further help you

Comment: sorry it doesn't work i gonna post again with more details

Comment: I spent quite a time to convince you to provide as much details as you can and after long back and forth fully answered your original question - the fact that you are getting more and more details afterwords does not mean that you should not accept the answer on the previously scoped question and than ask your new questions. good luck

Comment: @Renato - I can jump and help with you next question(s) - but first you need to accept this current one  - as it fully answers your initial question! as soon as you do  - i will consider checking you next question too o)

Comment: Hi Mikhail. I have realised that my initial question on this page was incorrect and should now be ignored. You´ve been very generous with your time and if you could please so kind as to help me with the corrected question, which can be found on this page:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633991/count-the-day-before-and-the-present-day

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Renato - i do understand that your above question was not exactly correct  - but I did answered it and it fully answered the question you posted  - so please accept it and I will be helping you in your next questions - otherwise i will not as it is a good chance that you will treat it same way!