# Count the day before and the present day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a code to count every route from bus by departure date, but i need to count the day before from route 148 plus the count of the route 139 for any day.

I have a view with variables:  DEP_DATE (DATE), DepartureDate (Datetime), Routes (Numeric) like this

```
DEP_DATE    DepartureDate Route= 139 Route= 148 Route=129 Route=61 Route=134 Route=60
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T15:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T10:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T08:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T21:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T13:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T06:30:00 0   0   0   11  0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T19:00:00 0   0   21  0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   10  13
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T17:30:00 0   0   2   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T05:30:00 1   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T14:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
08/02/2019  2019-02-08T07:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T20:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T22:00:00 0   2   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T20:30:00 0   0   8   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T07:00:00 0   0   0   12  0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T19:00:00 0   0   12  0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   20  7
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T15:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T06:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T08:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T18:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T14:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
09/02/2019  2019-02-09T13:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T21:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T10:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   11  11
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T13:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T08:15:00 0   0   0   22  0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T19:00:00 0   0   21  0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T07:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T20:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T15:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T20:30:00 0   1   2   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T06:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
10/02/2019  2019-02-10T18:15:00 0   0   0   10  0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T19:00:00 0   0   32  0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   14  12
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T00:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T15:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T08:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T13:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T06:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T07:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
11/02/2019  2019-02-11T10:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T13:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   10  8
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T15:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T10:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T07:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T14:45:00 0   0   0   15  0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T19:00:00 0   0   14  0   0   0
12/02/2019  2019-02-12T22:00:00 0   2   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T13:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T18:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T08:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T20:15:00 0   1   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T15:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T14:45:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T07:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   7   7
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T21:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T06:30:00 0   0   0   3   0   0
13/02/2019  2019-02-13T19:00:00 0   0   24  0   0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T18:15:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T20:30:00 0   0   3   0   0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T07:00:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T06:00:00 0   0   0   0   4   2
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T15:00:00 0   0   0   10  0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T19:00:00 0   0   10  0   0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T13:00:00 2   0   0   0   0   0
14/02/2019  2019-02-14T08:30:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And have my code that i made is like this:

```
 SELECT
 DEP_DATE,
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 139) + COUNTIF( RouteId = 148 AND DepartureDate = 
 DATETIME_SUB(departureDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS BUS_1,
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 134 ) + COUNTIF( RouteId = 60 ) AS BUS_2,
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 134 AND EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM  DepartureDate) = 6) + 
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 60 AND EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM  DepartureDate) = 6)  AS 
 BUS_3,
 FROM
 `project.dataset.view`

 WHERE
 DepartureDate > 
 DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME("America/Lima"), INTERVAL 3 
 DAY),DAY)  

 GROUP BY
 DEP_DATE
```

My results are like this

```
DEP_DATE Bus_1 Bus_2 Bus_3   Explanation_Bus_1:   Route_139  Route_148
08/02/2019  1   34  23                             1           0
09/02/2019  2   32  27                             0           2
10/02/2019  1   45  22                             0           1
11/02/2019  0   42  26                             0           0
12/02/2019  2   29  18                             2           0
13/02/2019  0   27  14                             0           1
14/02/2019  3   23  6                              2           0
```

But what i expect my count on "Bus_1" like this:

```
DEP_DATE Bus_1 Bus_2 Bus_3   Explanation_Bus_1:   Route_139  Route_148
08/02/2019  1   34  23                             1           0
09/02/2019  0   32  27                             0           2
10/02/2019  2   45  22                             0           1
11/02/2019  1   42  26                             0           0
12/02/2019  2   29  18                             2           0
13/02/2019  0   27  14                             0           1
14/02/2019  3   23  6                              2           0
```

Every count of the route 148 has to be count the day after in the Bus 1

Comment: For example, there is 1 count on the Bus_1 on date: "Monday, 2019-02-11" and 2 counts on "Tuesday, 2019-02-12" , i will expect those numbers counting in "Wednesday, 2019-02-13" with the count of this day (1+2+0).

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, please a i need some help

Comment: you should provide the input data! the data you shown as a view and query that you claim you have run against it  - have not much to do with each other. so, please-please read your own question again and make it clear and understood for others. otherwise answering it - is just waste of time ;o(

Comment: i don't know what you mean,i can't understand why you need more info in my question, it's clear, i already have a good advance with others, if you are not interesting, no problem, thanks

Comment: i am interested in helping you - and that is why I say what I say - read your question again and try to imagine that your are someone else who try to follow it  - you have example of data and query  - try to run that query against that example data  - it will not even run, but you claim you are getting some output, etc. so if you want us to help  - you need to do more work here. And what you reference as a good advance with others  - i do honestly not see this - this is more like blind try and catch - which i consider a time wasting

Comment: ok i understand your reasons, please let me work, i already say thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to check if the date is Friday, Wednesday or Saturday. If it is one of those days, then calculate else default to 0.

**Big Query Conditional Expressions:** https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions

**Big Query Date Functions:** https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

- DAYOFWEEK: Returns values in the range [1,7] with Sunday as the first day of the week.

Try this:

```
 SELECT
 T1.DEP_DATE,
 T2.BUS_1 AS BUS_1,
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 134 ) + COUNTIF( RouteId = 60 ) AS BUS_2,
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 134 AND EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM  DepartureDate) = 6) + 
 COUNTIF( RouteId = 60 AND EXTRACT(HOUR  FROM  DepartureDate) = 6)  AS 
 BUS_3,
 FROM
 `project.dataset.view` T1

 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DEP_DATE, 1, DAY) AS DEP_DATE,
        COUNTIF(RouteId = 139) + COUNTIF(RouteId = 148) AS BUS_1
    FROM project.dataset.view
    GROUP BY DEP_DATE
 ) T2
     ON T1.DEP_DATE = T2.DEP_DATE

 WHERE
 DepartureDate > 
 DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME("America/Lima"), INTERVAL 3 
 DAY),DAY) 

 GROUP BY
 T1.DEP_DATE, T2.BUS_1
```

Comment: i got these error: "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword AS at [9:94]". In this part: CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DEP_DATE) IN (4,6,7) THEN 0 ELSE COUNTIF( RouteId = 148 ) AS BUS_1,

Comment: i think i express myself wrong, i need wednesday to be the sum of the counts of monday and tuesday and wednesday too(monday and tuesday with 0 count), for Friday i need  the sum of the counts of thursday and friday (thursday with 0 count), and finally sunday the sum of the counts of saturday and sunday (saturday with 0 count)

Comment: @RenatoMartinGalvezCastillo Ah yes! That does changes things. Please update your original question. Are you still getting the unexpected keyword error?

Comment: Check if the error is gone with my latest edit. I'll check again on how to get the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Hey @Rika my superior change the logic, sorry!!!, i have to count the day before in the route 148 plus the count of the day of the route 139 in the Bus 1, i already update the question.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and how to calculate it with examples?

Comment: how can i do that??, do I have to send you a link or json file ??

Comment: any success??, please let me know as soon as you done!!

Comment: I used a left join to get data from the previous day and calculate the counts. Let me know if it works!

Comment: DEP_DATE is a Date not a string !!!, sorry i update the info on the question, my bad

Comment: what you mean with this "WHERE route_139 <> 0 or route_148 <> 0", routes_139 is not a count is route where the bus is going, that's why i use Countif (Route = 139)

Comment: It says that i have to groupped "Route"  and  "BUS_1", when i do that it gives me several dates with the same date

Comment: Added in the group by. Try now